# Catkin build fails to find reference to library inside the same package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all! first of all, english is not my native language :D I'm sorry if there are too many mistakes, here we go.

I decided to add a library `master_utils` inside the package `master_core` to add some extended functions to some msg types created inside the package. I followed the [docs](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html) to add/install the library with the rest of the package.

The strange situation that I'm going through is:

- When calling a function defined in `master_utils` from another package (adding `master_core` as dependecy and `#include <master_core/master_utils.h>`) it builds with no error and has the expected result.
- When calling the same function defined in `master_utils` on the file `RSI_parser.cpp` (both inside the same package `master_core`) I get a build error.

The error catkin build throws is:

```
/home/lewis/master/mestrado/src/ROS/catkin_ws/src/master_core/src/controller/RSI_parser.cpp:37: error: undefined reference to `stampedTFtoKukaPose(tf::StampedTransform&, master_core::KukaPose_<std::allocator<void> >&)'
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944762/call-to-function-in-header-of-other-file-undefined-reference) that is closely related to my problem, but didn't find anything related to the solution on the docs page I was following. Maybe that points that the problem is more related to CMakeLists than to ROS.

I don't know if it's related, but when adding the `#include` on `.cpp` files, all of the generated headers are duplicated on QT auto completion, except `master_utils`.

The package structure and files are as the following:

package structure:

```
master_core
-include
  -master_core
    -master_utils.h
-src
  -master_utils.cpp
  -controller
    -RSI_parser.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt (Omitting some add_executable/add_dependencies/target_link_libraries from other nodes)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(master_core)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  message_generation
  geometry_msgs
  tf
  master_moveit
  moveit_ros_planning_interface
  urdf
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  RobotAxis.msg
  KukaPose.msg
  RSI.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
  geometry_msgs
  moveit_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES master_utils
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp
  message_runtime
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(master_utils src/master_utils.cpp)
add_dependencies(master_utils ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(master_utils ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(RSI_node src/controller/RSI_parser.cpp)
add_dependencies(RSI_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(RSI_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS master_utils
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )

 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
 )
```

master_utils.h

```
#ifndef MASTER_UTILS_H
#define MASTER_UTILS_H

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <master_core/KukaPose.h>
#include <master_core/RSI.h>
#include <master_core/RobotAxis.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>

void stampedTFtoKukaPose(tf::StampedTransform&, master_core::KukaPose&);

#endif
```

RSI_parser.cpp

```
...
#include <master_core/master_utils.h>
...

...
void sendRSI() {
...
tf::StampedTransform ref_to_RIst;
master_core::KukaPose RIst;
stampedTFtoKukaPose(ref_to_RIst, RIst);
...
}
```

I think maybe I left a configuration out of CMakeLists.txt, or am missing a concept about the compiler. (The probability is high, as I'm no C++ expert)

Do I have to develop libraries on a separate package or is it possible to develop it as extension from the same package as I'm trying to do?

Thank you very much for your attention!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351417/catkin-build-fails-to-find-reference-to-library-inside-the-same-package/) by [lewis_ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/54194/lewis_ferreira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you got here is a linker error. The compiler cannot resolve, in the `RSI_parser.cpp`, where the function `stampedTFtoKukaPose` is implemented. After all, you only have the declaration included.

You need to tell CMake to link your executable against the library containing the implementation. I.e.

```
target_link_libraries(RSI_node master_utils ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

This must be done explicitly if the library is built in the same package, as the `catkin_LIBRARIES` variables only captures the libraries that are `find_package`'d.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lewis_ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/54194/lewis_ferreira/) on 2020-05-05**:
Thank you! Clear and straight forward explanation!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-05-05**:
happy to help!